# How do you record from two USB microphones using PyAudio?

Tags: python, fft, microphone, pyaudio

My application requires recording from two microphones at different locations simultaneously, and then doing FFT on the two streams of data to obtain a result. I was not able to find how to do this using PyAudio. Here is a code for recording from one source:

```
CHUNK = 1024
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 1
RATE = 44100
RECORD_SECONDS = 2

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

stream = p.open(format=FORMAT,
                channels=CHANNELS,
                rate=RATE,
                input=True,
                frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)

frames = []

for i in range(0, int(RATE / CHUNK * RECORD_SECONDS)):
    data = stream.read(CHUNK)
    frames.append(data)

stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
p.terminate()
```

Do I have to create two streams? And even if I code it right, are there hardware (sound card) limitations for this that I need to look into? Thanks

Comment: Yes and yes. The details on the second yes are very extensive and depend largely on the exact setup.

Comment: you may want one thread per channel and a third thread for the rest of your code which combines both streams and does the fft

Comment: create two stream (thread) for two mic and make use of 'input_device_index' parameter in Stream class.

Answer (score 0):

When using two independent audio devices, they will each have their own clock, and will drift from each other over time.

If you need to record from multiple microphones, you'll want to attach them to the same audio interface.  (Or, synchronize the two audio interfaces via their word clock, or by physically modifying them if no word clock I/O is available.)

Answer (score 0):

to record from 2 Mics at once, you'll need to use a threaded based solution
simply assign each mic to his own thread, and you can work parallel

please note that stream starting time will differ, without a sampler it will be hard to sync them on the MS level.